# Magento 2: CDN Recommended for Magento 2, Community Edition

Tags: magento2, css, full-page-cache, magento2.3.2, cdn

We were examining the possibility of adding a CDN service for our platforms on Magento 2.
However, this possibility had already been adopted in the past and had created several problems with the management of FPC and some styles, but this on Magento 1.
Is there any recommended service that can be used that is as close as possible to the Magento platform?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use https://www.cloudflare.com to add CDN on magento 2

Comment: issues are the same as magento 1. you need to send proper in time invalidation request

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend Fastly. Its module in the marketplace is always up-to-date, it works perfectly from version 2.3 of Magento, it can be managed from Magento Admin and you can even use it to control the FPC of magento, optimize images and others.

It is the CDN used today by Magento Cloud, but the Fastly module is available for Open-Source and Enterprise

https://marketplace.magento.com/fastly-magento2.html